# Can using the mean of absolute Shapely Values for feature importance give very wrong results?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, data-science-model, shap

In a classification problem, suppose a model has **2** variables, **A** and **B**, and the **null model** (the model without any variable) predicts 50% probability for belonging to class 1 for all the instances.

Now suppose that for all the data instances **xi**, feature **A** makes the model to predict the opposite value of the correct class with a large magnitude(i.e. if the true class is 1 and the null model predicts 0.5, **A** makes the model to predict 0.1 probability), and **B** makes the model to predict toward the correct class but with less magnitude (i.e. if the true class is 1 and the null model predicts 0.5, adding B makes the model to predict 0.57). This means that the feature **B is actually a better feature than **A** but the impact of **A** is stronger than **B**.

One common way of calculating the feature importance is calculating the average of the absolute Shapley values for all the instances for feature **A** and **B**. The example that I just gave shows that this method of finding feature importance using mean absolute value would give **wrong results** since it would give feature **A** a higher importance that feature **B**.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct in your analysis, but have used a very unusual context.  It would be an impressively bad model that uses $A$ confidently in the wrong direction.

If such a situation did occur, then shap is still answering the question "which features are impactful on the output?" correctly: $A$ has the larger impact on decisions.  Shap can only tell you about the model, and that only proxies for reality if the model is reasonably good.